# How to save Features and then draw them by data in a file? Openlayers

Tags: save, draw, openlayers

I need to save the features drawn into a file, and then, by a combo or something, let the user load those specific features.

Until now, I got the following code from my features, as an example:

```
    {"type":"Feature","id":"OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_250","properties":{},"geometry": 
    {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[99200,105250],[99800,99750],[103050,102600],[99200,105250]]]},"crs":
    {"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":221951}}}

    {"type":"Feature","id":"OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_256","properties":{},"geometry":
    {"type":"Point","coordinates":[97500,102100]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":221951}}}

    {"type":"Feature","id":"OpenLayers.Feature.Vector_278","properties":{},"geometry":
    {"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[97900,104350],[98450,100550]]},"crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":
    {"code":221951}}}
```

Those are a Polygon, a Point and a Line. Now I want to, from that data, redraw them anytime the user wants to.
File managment is not an issue, I just need to know how to put those guys on the map again.

I saw that this guy does something like that, http://thinkwhere.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/geocommons-geojson-in-openlayers/, but he uses a Feature Collection...that may be a possibility...

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!